# Unit testing for Combination of inputs

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, xunit

I am working for an application that has set of filter options to filter the data.

I want to test each combination of input for which my method is going to work. For example do I have to write Unit test for each combination like below:

```
[TestClass]
public class Data_Should_Filter
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void _For_Category()
    {

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void _For_Product_And_Category()
    {

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void _For_Product_CreationDate()
    {

    }
}
```

Is there any way to test each combination of data with single test. I review the [blog](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2015/04/combinatorial-and-pairwise-testing-with-nunit/) for NUnit test. What are the possible way to achieve this kind of testing and which are the frameworks that support combination testing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible with NUnit 2.5 and above

```
[TestCase(12,3,4)]
[TestCase(12,2,6)]
[TestCase(12,4,3)]
public void DivideTest(int n, int d, int q)
{
    Assert.AreEqual( q, n / d );
}
```

Some more info [here](http://nunit.org/docs/2.5.5/testCase.html)

Comment: Thank you for details but as you can see that we have to provide TestCase here. I want to know is there any framework that can do this automatically. I researched an found FsCheck can work but have no experience with it.

Comment: So you want something to read your code and create unit tests for it automatically?  I think that's called a programmer or developer etc...

Comment: In that case you might want to look into https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Theory-Attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't given any examples of what you want to automatically combine, so I have had to invent it for this answer.

NUnit has several ways to specify data as a argument corresponding to a single parameter of the test method as well as several ways of combining those arguments.

Specify arguments:
 * ValuesAttribute
 * ValueSourceAttribute
 * RandomAttribute
 * RangeAttribute

Generate combinations of the above values:
 * CombinatorialAttribute (this one is the default if you don't use anything)
 * PairwiseAtribute
 * SequentialAttribute

Example...

```
[Test]
public void TestProcuctAndCategory(
    [Values("ProductA", ProductB")] string productName,
    [Values("Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat3")] string category)
{
    // Test will be executed six times, using all combinations
    // of the values provided for the two arguments.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible with Nunit:

```
[TestFixture]
    public class Data_Should_Filter
    {
        [Test]
        [TestCase(new Product(1), new Category(2), DateTime.UtcNow)]
        [TestCase(new Product(2), new Category(2), DateTime.UtcNow)]
        public void TestFilter(Product product, Category category, DateTime creationDate)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Found this library which can be used for Random combinations testing:
[FsCheck](https://github.com/fscheck/FsCheck)